# How to get a button to move a widget in relation to its current position every time the button is pressed?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Here's my attempt at making this work:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.on_click()
    def initUI(self):
        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.move(100,200)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    
    def on_click(self):
        text = QTextEdit(self)
        insideText = "Text"
        text.document().setPlainText(insideText)
        text.resize(100,25) 
        print('PyQt5 button click')
        position = text.pos()
        text.move(position.x()+50,position.y()+0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Maybe I need to make the QTextEdit go somewhere in the initUI() method, instead of being defined in on_click(). I already tried this but I get "text is not defined", and I'm not sure how to reference it inside another function/method. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Here's the working code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton,QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.on_click()
    def initUI(self):
        self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        self.button.move(100,200)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.text = QTextEdit(self)
        insideText = "Text"
        self.text.document().setPlainText(insideText)
        self.text.resize(100,25)


    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')
        position = self.text.pos()
        self.text.move(position.x()+50,position.y()+0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to reference it inside another function/method" - your widgets should become *instance attributes* of your `App` class - by writing `self.button = QPushButton( ...)` and `self.text = QTextEdit( ...)`, you can reference the widgets from within any method with `self.button` and `self.text`, respectively.

Comment: Note that, ideally, you initialize all attributes (widgets or otherwise) in the `__init__` method. Creating attributes in other methods is an easy way to get bugs, because you may forget to call the method and rely on an attribute that does not exist. You can create a widget while keeping it hidden by using its `setVisible` method.

Comment: Ah, thank you!! I got it to work by adding self in front of "text" and adding the text variable and it's attributes to the App class.